# Windows Azure VPN Feature

Tags: azure

I was wondering if I convinced my manager to deploy Azure in the next project. Would it be possible to access the VPN resources from the Azure cloud Services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes but you'll need a [supported Cisco or Juniper device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156075.aspx) on-premises. If you don't have such a device, try looking at [Windows Azure Connect](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/plankytronixx/archive/2010/11/09/azure-connect-connecting-your-on-premise-and-windows-azure-networks-together.aspx) which can give you an experience similar to VPN.

Comment: Thanks for the link as I am new to Azure and do not know the whole set of features it can offer.

Answer (score 0):

@Sandrino, depends on what you meant by VPN, just want to point out, Azure Connect is using IPSEC to secure connection end to end.

Answer (score 0):

Other routers such as fortinet can also support side to side vpn to azure, I myself use a fortinet device to connect to azure, if you need help let me know.